# AOT query can reference a TempDB table as a data source

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

We use AX 2012 R3.

[Temporary TempDB Tables [AX 2012]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg845661.aspx) states that *A query under **AOT** > **Queries** can reference a TempDB table as a data source.*

**My question**: How does an AOT query read the records written into a data source that is a TempDB table?

The problem that I have is that the AOT query seems unable to read any record from my TempDB table data source:

I defined a TempDB table under AOT, and I also created an AOT query which references this TempDB table as a data source.

I write a method to fill out the TempDB table and then I write a `while queryRun` loop, passed with the AOT query object mentioned above. However, the loop body was never run.

I have made sure that the code is written correctly: if I changed the TempDB table into a Regular table, the loop body is entered and generates the results correctly.

(Alternatively, I have written a `while select` instead of the `queryRun` of the AOT query. The `while select` loop generates correct results, regardless of whether the joined table is TempDB or Regular. **However**, I want to allow adding other ranges. A `while select` loop seems not able to do this. So, I use a `while queryRun` loop following some `SysQuery::findOrCreateRange`.)

The link above also states that *a TempDB table exists only during the scope of a method that instantiates it*. The filling out of TempDB table and the loop  that I wrote are done in the same method. But, as I never instantiate a table, what is meant by *to instantiate it(a TempDB table)*?

**EDIT**s: 1) I also tried to write some code following the `while queryRun` loop to see if there are records in the TempDB table, and found that the records are still present in the TempDB table.
2) To clarify, a `while queryRun` loop means the following

```
QueryRun queryRun = new QueryRun(query);
while(queryRun.next()){...}
```

The `query` in the instantiation of `queryRun` above is an AOT query object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you fill the `TempDb` table you need to pass it to the query via `queryRun.setRecord([TempDb Table])`

Then do your `while(queryRun.next()){...}`

Comment: Thanks! It solves my problem! It would be nicer if you could provide some explanations or references.

Comment: Glad I could help. It's fairly straight forward after you figure out the pieces. TempDb is temp table that exists in the scope it's instantiated in. The Query object in the AOT is a sort of abstract structure that connects schema objects, and is able to be interpreted in the AX query framework. So when you try and use the query, you need to pass the instance of the temp table like a variable.

Comment: I don't have AX in front of me, so I'm going from memory, but one thing to note, `TempDb` tables when passing data or setting on forms should use `linkPhysicalTableInstance(...)` while `In-Memory` tables should use `setTmpData(...)`. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/axsupport/2012/08/09/temporary-tables-ax-2012/

Comment: How can we do that with AOT query ? The UI query ? Where do i override the query behavior to fill the temp table and then join the values ? Can we do this in AOT query ?